# VSC unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace weird

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started using VSCode version 1.24.1.

After loading a folder, it shows warning

> Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace

After i check the limit as suggested on their  [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc), using

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

I get 8192, while my project has only 650 files (of which 400 are inside .git)

Why does this happen? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

(Increasing the limit is clearly not the right solution.)

Comment: Have you tried to increase the limit? From the same page: “The limit can be increased to its maximum by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and adding this line to the end of the file: `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`”, followed by `sudo sysctl -p`.

Comment: That is not a solution. Check my answer after 5 min. I think I got it.

Comment: The limit is not just for Visual Studio, and may have been exceeded even before VSCode is launched

Comment: VSCode 1.61 (Sept. 2021) comes with a new files watcher which should improve this issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The fact that you are out of watches does not mean that its `VSCode`'s fault.

`VSCode` has for sure issues with excluding directories from watch (on linux) (update: most are recently resolved [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132483), and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40898))

But since you have counted the files yourself, the error message in this case is probably misleading and **some other application has already exhausted watches**.

To trace the guilty app you can use [this nice script](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers)

Answer (score 108):

what linux ppl dont know, there are ppl new to linux like me. So if you're a noob, this is for you.

1. Open a new `terminal`.
2. `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` (might be a number 8k+)

now `(a)` for `vim`-Editor

3. (a) `sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf`
4. (a) go all the way down and add a new line with: `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` (make sure you **DONT** have a `#` in front of the command)
5. (a) type `:wq!` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

or `(b)` for `nano`-Editor (thanks to @bradrar)

3. (b) `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`
4. (b) go all the way down and add a new line with: `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` (make sure you **DONT** have a `#` in front of the command)
5. (b) type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, type <kbd>y</kbd> and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

---

6. type `sudo sysctl -p`
7. type again: `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` (should be 500k+ now)
8. (thank me later.)

Comment: for people who don't have vim, try `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` , then step 4, then instead of `:wq!` hit ctrl+x, click y and enter

Comment: I'm confused - do I run this on my local macOS, or on the remote? (centos in my current case) Those files don't exist on my macOS, but does on the remote...

Comment: this is a linux solution. dont know about any mac related stuff...

Comment: This does not answer the OP’s question _precisely_ in the way that they wrote they would like it not to be answered (“Increasing the limit is clearly not the right solution”).

Answer (score 32):

The solution I found and it's work for me is

add this line `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` in to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

and then run the command `sudo sysctl -p`

and then go to your vscode settings find a file called `settings.json`

and this line to it

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true
  }
```

you can also refer this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

Comment: My project has only 650 files (of which 400 are inside .git), so I don't think that is the acceptable solution.

Comment: Not working for me. Rather not increase the file size at OS level

Comment: set `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` worked for me

Comment: Editing `files.watcherExclude` would be a nice solution if [this persistent bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40898) did not exist. And I bet it's gonna stay there for long..

Comment: will this prevent vscode from detecting git related code changes?

Comment: @mike01010 no, what this answer lists is the default `watcherExclude` of VSCode, not something they added. So by default VSCode excludes some git objects and caches, which does not impact its git functionality

Answer (score 8):

In my case I do not have enough privileges to change the `sysctl.conf`, so my solution for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was:

```
sudo /bin/su -c "echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: what do you mean that you do not have the priviledge to change `sysctl.conf` when you can use `sudo` and attach text to the file? :)

Answer (score 8):

In my case (PHP using Composer), I had to exclude `vendor` path from watching

[image]

Depending on your case, you should exclude your dependencies folder.

Comment: Correct ! Wishing this was more obvious. For Python users, note that VSCode is trying to watch your environment folder, i.e. `miniconda3/envs/my_env_name/...`.

Answer (score 7):

Following settings worked for me (inside `.vscode/settings.json`, you can also put them at user level / system level settings in vscode instead of workspace level settings)

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/some-soft-link-to-higher-level-directory-in-my-file-system" : true,
        "**/.cache-loader" : true
}
```

`.git, node_modules` are perhaps excluded by default, but depending on your workspace, you may need to add others. As an example, I had a soft link to a higher level directory in my file-system (which recursively had 100s of thousands of files). Similarly, `.cache-loader` often has thousands of files.

*Possibly useful note:* it took me some time to realize that `files.exclude` and `files.watcherExclude` are two different settings.

*Some theoretical opinion:* Most answers here (and even in the official vscode documentation) suggest increasing the system watcher limits to a very large number. This works okay in most cases, however, it is like using a hammer in place of a screwdriver (is brute force, may not always work, and is not efficient). While the absolute system limit can (and perhaps should be) raised from the default limit, it is beneficial to optimize your workspace and avoid using unnecessary system resources.

Comment: Is this `watcherExclude` set per workspace or per User/globally?

Comment: @Foton both should work. If you are collaborating with others and the soft link is part of the repository, better to put it in workspace config. If the link is restricted to your machine, you should put it in User config.

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes. I've upped the watcher limits in the past, which is helpful, but recently added a symlink to a directory with a massive number of data files. The `files.watcherExclude` setting worked like a charm.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, still get warning at startup.  I can't do the other suggestions on a work computer due to permissions either...

Comment: Should these have wildcards?
` "**/.git": true,` doesn't work for me as I would expect

Comment: @terary In the official documentation  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings files.exclude has   entries like   `"**/.git": true`,  while watcherExclude has entries like   `"**/.git/objects/**": true,  "**/node_modules/*/**": true` etc. I am not sure if this is by design or just due to random examples in documentation. 

Will need to test (I realized that even I have been using a combination of settings with wildcards and without wildcards - perhaps that is why performance in my vscode has been slow as of late because some of them don't work as expected).

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

The limit can be increased to its maximum by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and adding this line to the end of the file: `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`

The new value can then be loaded in by running `sudo sysctl -p`

Answer (score 5):

Oct. 2021: this is improved from VSCode 1.61 (Sept. 2021, see below)

VSCode 1.62 includes:

> ### [File watching changes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_62.md#engineering)

> File watching in VS Code changes to a new library, thanks to the work of the Parcel team with their [`@parcel/watcher`](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/watcher).
> We will gradually roll out this change to all users in the upcoming weeks.
> Linux users will be happy to learn that the `files.watcherExclude` now applies natively so that the number of file handles VS Code needs to open for file watching can be greatly reduced.
>
> The existing `files.legacyWatcher` setting was changed to an enumeration with these values:
>
> - **`on`** - The new file watcher will never be used.
> - **`off`** - The new file watcher will always be used.
> - **`default`** - The new file watcher will only be used when you open multi-root workspaces (via `.code-workspace` file).

---

Feb. 2021: As noted in [issue 40898](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40898), the issue persists for the multi-root workspace (see the last part, for VSCode 1.61 improvements)

> Initial problem is that the `npm` install takes twice as long to install dependencies when VSCode is running.
>
> I've figured out that this is because of file watching for the node_modules folder so I added it to `files.watcherExclude`.
>
> I use the following combinations (but non of them seems to be working):
>
> ```yaml
> "files.watcherExclude": {
>        "**/node_modules": true,
>        "**/node_modules/**": true,
>        "**/node_modules/*/**": true
>    }
> ```

This [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40898#issuecomment-786218663) points out [a script](https://gist.github.com/dirkfeytons/bf0acb8fe9888dafb1e6635b9de341ed) from  [Dirk Feytons](https://github.com/dirkfeytons) to see which inotify watches are actually being created to confirm whether my watcher excludes were being used or not.

```c
/*
 * If you want to see which inotify watches are being created by an application then you can
 * use this simple piece of code, compile it to a shared library and LD_PRELOAD it when starting
 * the application. Keep an eye on syslog to see the list of watches.
 * **NOTE**: This only logs the watches, it won't actually create the watch and thus watching
 * for changes WON'T actually WORK!
 *
 * More details (adjust as needed for your environment/distribution):
 * - Save this file in e.g. $HOME/inotify.c
 * - Compile: gcc -shared -o inotify.so inotify.c
 * - Start monitoring syslog: tail -f -n 0 /var/log/syslog | tee $HOME/watches.log
 * - Run your application with: LD_PRELOAD=$HOME/inotify.so <application>
 */

#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>

int inotify_add_watch(int fd, const char *pathname, uint32_t mask)
{
    syslog(LOG_USER | LOG_ERR, "********** [%u] inotify_add_watch for %s", getpid(), pathname);
    return 100000;
}
```

---

Update [Sept. 2021](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40898#issuecomment-925993476), from [Lionel Gatibelza](https://github.com/lgatibel):

> I was able to fix the problem, I don't know the real cause and why Vscode performed this check for the error, but I did the known fix on the remote server and on my local machine:
>
> - Add this `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`
> - Reload the configuration: `sudo sysctl -p`
> - Close and reopen vscode
>   After that I didn't have the error again!

And [from issue 132483](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132483#issuecomment-925585026) from [Benjamin Pasero](https://github.com/bpasero) (software engineer at Microsoft in Zurich):

> Just to clarify, `nsfw` is used on Windows as well in multi-root workspaces.
> It was our original intent 5y ago to replace all other watching solutions with `nsfw` so we enabled it only for multi-root scenarios, which target a lower user base (maybe 200.000 users) to get some testing and feedback.
> The next step in this journey is to enable it for all users and remove the others.
>
> PS: the only platform where `nsfw` is currently not enabled by default (unless you are in a multi-root workspace) is Linux because unfortunately `nsfw` does not support ignore patterns (our `files.watcherExclude` setting) and each folder in a hierarchy is counted as an opened file handle against the limited set of file handles in the OS, forcing users to increase that limit.
> The plan is to implement that support in October and then also get Linux on board.

---

Sept. 2021, VSCode 1.61:

> ### [File watching changes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/4be6a55f95a85b4a6a865e5785f5ef89a54e631f/release-notes/v1_61.md#file-watching-changes)
>
> The file watcher used to detect changes to files and folders on disk changed to a library that can handle all of our supported platforms (Windows, Linux, macOS) and reduces the overhead of maintaining different watchers for different platforms.
>
> We plan to enable this library by default on all platforms. This iteration we enabled it on Windows and macOS, while Linux is planned shortly after.
>
> The new watcher should be faster on startup, resulting in fewer CPU cycles spent on large folders.
>
> One downside of using the library is that the file watcher no longer automatically detects folders in a workspace that are symbolic links on macOS.
> If you have such a setup, you can use the new `files.watcherInclude` setting to add symbolic link paths to include for file watching explicitly.
>
> On the upside, you can use this new setting on Windows to explicitly include symbolic link folders inside the workspace - something that was not possible before on Windows.
>
> You should not notice any difference in your day to day work, but if file watching is broken for you, please report an issue.
> There is a setting `files.legacyWatcher` to enable the old watcher in case of problems.

Answer (score 1):

## TL; DR;

Seems like a bug.

## -----

It seems the warning is gone now.

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the bug right now, but here are some steps.

- Installed Php Intellisense extension
- From linux terminal did `git init`
- Added folder into workspace
- Did some work, added, saved, commit and push from command palette
- closed VSC
- Opened VSC -> warning was shown.

At this moment i saw in `htop` that there was a process `/usr/share/code` with long arguments which included something with `TypeScript` that was using 100% of 1 CPU and around 1G RAM. Then

- closes VSC
- killed process
- opened VSC

Now the warning is not showing anymore, also CPU is being used normally.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was creating a separate workspace for the project i was working on. So if i'm working on something in /htdocs/project/ then instead of just opening that folder i create it as a workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the recommendations from
[https://stackoverflow.com/users/4270633/harsh-shah[harsh-shah][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4270633/harsh-shah%5Bharsh-shah%5D%5B1%5D)

Almost worked for me.  I discovered I had resources in my project that were also being watched unnecessary.

VScode behavior seems to be watch everything, unless excluded.

If you find you have a couple hundred files in your project but have 32000 watchers - you may want to inventory what is in your project directory and exclude unnecessary directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using for **JavaScript** development, there is a workaround:

Just disable this built-in extension: **TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**

Answer (score 0):

For those using **Pylance**, setting `"files.watcherExclude"` may not suffice. The extension watches all paths reported by python `sys.path`.

source: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2914#issuecomment-1154254992

Deactivating the extension is one, admittedly imperfect, solution if increasing `max_user_watches` is not an options.

Answer (score 0):

Raising the file limits of the system really only papers over the problem.

Are you really going to raise the watcher limit over the 100s of thousands that it already is at?

Instead, search in the repo for folders with a tone of files in them:

```
du --inodes -S | sort -rh | sed -n \
        '1,50{/^.\{71\}/s/^\(.\{30\}\).*\(.\{37\}\)$/\1...\2/;p}'
```

vscode should already exclude node_modules and .git by default, so it is probably other folders that you have, likely auto-generated files from some app (a compilation or directory target, etc).

This one ignores .git and node_modules directories:

```
du --inodes -S | grep -v "node_modules" | grep -v ".git" | sort -rh | sed -n \
    '1,50{/^.\{71\}/s/^\(.\{30\}\).*\(.\{37\}\)$/\1...\2/;p}'
```

You could also just remove recursively your node_modules if you are confident in running a fresh npm install.  To remove:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem is due to the directory level on which you open your file explorer.  That is, when you open the file explorer, VS code auto-fills the directory to open with /home/yourUsername.  If you accept this, then it only watches files in your home directory.  However, if you change this to the root ( / ), then it will create file watches for everything in the entire OS, and devour your system resources.

Since you're not connecting remotely as root (right?), you can't access root-level directories through the file explorer anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing **Javascript**, then this is probably gonna work for this issue:

You have to access the side-bar extensions menu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
Then type: `@builtin types` and **disable** the extension: `TypeScript and JavaScript language features`.