# Visual Studio Code: Unable to watch for file changes. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often get the "Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace" -error and I can't figure out why.

```
Visual Studio Code (Linux): 1.24.1
```

My exclude setting is:

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true,
    "**/.svn/**": true,
    "**/dist/**": true,
    "**/dist-prod/**":true
}
```

The structure of the project is:

```
angular.json
/dist
/dist-prod
/e2e
ngsw-config.json
/node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
proxy.conf.json
README.md
/src
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
xliffmerge.json
.editorconfig
.gitignore
/.svn
```

/src contains only 167 files and folders. I suspect that node_modules is not really excluded. But I can't know for sure. Is my settings correct?

The problem goes away after VSC is restarted, but it always comes back after a while...

Comment: I have also experienced (and continue to experience) this issue. I've opened https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/59679

Comment: Nice move Jack :-) I used the workaround that seems to be the general approach, but it just feels wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901127/vsc-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-weird#comment88802139_50901127

Comment: I also think that the problem is that node_modules isn't really excluded. I got the warning after installing a new module, and excluding node_modules I only have around 20 files in my project. `Watcher exclude` is set to the default values, which includes `**/node_modules/**`

Answer (score 7):

you've to increase the limit. Follow the below procedure:

1. Check the current limit `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`
2. edit sysctl.conf file in vim editor `sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf`
3. Add this line at bottom `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`
4. save it (esc) `:wq!`
5. To load the change `sudo sysctl -p`
6. now check again `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

if the count is same, execute the following command

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

[For more details](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Increasing max_user_watches seems like a way to just handle the symptom. It does not cure the underlying disease. 

15 months ago, when I wrote this question, I was wondering if the "Watcher Exclude" function had a bug. I configured it to exclude node_modules and other folders it should ignore.
Clearly it should not be necessary to increase max_user_watches in a small project of 167 files. And when I watched the output, it seemed to me that it went through a lot more files than that...

This bug could very well be fixed. One of these days I'll decrease max_user_watches to check it.

Comment: Almost all the things like node_modules are added in watch exclude list by default. yes obviously we can include more item, if we want as you suggested. We can disable active unwanted extensions also.

Comment: I really dislike that this is the only answer I can find. My project has 3 files that I actually want watched, I can increase max_user_watches but the performance hit is significant. My laptop is 9 years old, it doesn't need the extra stress :/