# Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace" (error ENOSPC) #29

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

My IDE is not monitoring. I'm using VS code editor. I'm getting the following error

```
Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace" (error ENOSPC) #29
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve the level of detail in your question.

Comment: https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/issues/29 Maybe this can help you out

Comment: You have to change the watch limit
Please refer this [VS code is unable to watch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58798235/10907720)

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is ranking in Google for this issue and there isn't a great answer for it,

Here's how to change the watch limit on Ubuntu:

1. Run `sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf`
2. At the bottom of the file, add `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`
3. Save the file
4. Run `sudo sysctl -p`
5. Running `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` should return `524288`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you marked this question with **angular**, and there is a workaround for this specific case.

This problem is probably due to this extension: **TypeScript and JavaScript language features**

Just disable it:

[image: TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features]

For those who are **not using JavaScript**: You can also, use [this](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers) script to see which process is consuming the most of these watchers.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the extension: **TypeScript and JavaScript language features**.
that is a built-in extension. To find it you have to access the side-bar extensions menu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. Then type: `@builtin types`. Probably the first one. Open it then. Disable.