# VS Code unable to watch for file changes in CentOS with tcsh shell

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, centos7, tcsh

I'm encountering an issue with Visual Studio Code on Linux. The problem is that VS Code is unable to watch for file changes in my workspace, even though `files.watcherExclude` is configured and I certainly have a small file count. I'm launching VSC from shell.

**Setup details:**

- System: CentOS
- Shell: tcsh
- Workspace Structure:

  ```css
  workspace-folder/
  ├── dev/
  │   └── code/
  │       └── .vscode/
  ├── data/
  └── results/
  ```

  *Please note that the git repository is located in the code folder, which is the only directory that VSC should monitor. The data and results folders are included in the workspace solely for periodic inspection.*

I have configured the `files.watcherExclude` setting in VS Code as follows:

```json
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "code/.git/objects/**": true,
    "code/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "code/node_modules/*/**": true,
    "code/node_modules": true,
    "code/.hg/store/**": true,
    "**/.git/objects/**" : true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true,
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/.hg/store/**": true,
    "**/data/**": true,
    "**/results/** ": true,
    "**/__pycache__/**": true,
    "**/.pytest_cache/**": true
}
```

I've come across this [PR](https://github.com/Axosoft/nsfw/pull/124) which inspired my `files.watcherExclude` configuration. I have attempted to make the paths explicit to address the problem.

I've also ran couple of commands to count files and symlinks in `workspace-folder`. Outputs:

```bash
$ find -L /workspace-folder -type f | wc -l
1923
$ find /workspace-folder -type l | wc -l
0
$ find -L /workspace-folder/dev/code -type f | wc -l
207
$ find /workspace-folder/dev/code -type l | wc -l
0
```

I have already reviewed the solutions mentioned in the Visual Studio Code documentation and the following answers (among many others) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56292289/13517553), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58798235/13517553)) regarding increasing the number of watches. However, these solutions require sudo privileges, which I do not have.

**Questions:**

1. How is it possible for the VS Code file watcher to exceed 8000+ files, while my entire file count is under 1500?
2. Can you provide any hints or suggestions on how to solve this problem without requiring sudo privileges?

Comment: side info: in order to make sure that no other applications are exhausting the watches, I run [this script](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers) whenever I get a notification from vsc. The result is always two `.vscode-server` processes, one of which has an 8000+ watches count.

Comment: any symlinks anywhere here? see also the `-L` flag of `find`. default for find is `-P`.

Comment: @starball yes, I'm launching vscode from tcsh.

Comment: I've edited the post accordingly. And added a note to the worspace structure. I assumed that the output `find . -type l` would be redundant.

Comment: Aside: I remember using tcsh, it was a nightmare. Switch now, thank me later.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit I generally prefer bash. But I'm not sure if I can switch in my case, I have to work with a batch system that runs a tcsh.